# how to make a href connection to folder and variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display my images from database. I have a variable named as $image. This variable contains jpeg names and I have a folder named as uploads which stores the images. I am looking to display my images in large size when clicking the thumbnail image Please Help me Anyone............

this is my code

```
     <?php
     include("connection.php");
     $target="uploads/thumbnails/";
     $email=$_SESSION['email'];
     if($email==NULL)
     {
          header("location:register.php");
     }
     else
     {
         $start=0;
         $limit=2;
         $page=1;
         if(isset($_GET['page']))
         {
             $page=$_GET['page'];
             $start=($page-1)*$limit;
         }
         $sql=mysql_query("select * from photos where email='$email' LIMIT  $start,$limit");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
         {
             $image=$row['image_name'];
             echo $image;
         ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="uploads/".$image>//Error in this line
    <img src="<?php echo $target.$row['thumb']; ?>" /></a>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
        $query=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from photos where '$email'=email"));
        $total=ceil($query/$limit);
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$page)
            {
                echo  $i;
            }
            else
            {   
                echo "<a href='?page=".$i."'>"."     ".$i."</a>";

            }
        }

  }

        ?>
```

Comment: check this part of code `where '$email'=email"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write that error line like this

```
 <a target="_blank" href="uploads/<?php echo $image ?>">//Error in this line
```